# Redirect to new page on Dialog close

Tags: jsf, dialog, primefaces

I'm trying to get a redirect to a new page once the primeface dialog is closed. I've tried with ajax close event inside the dialog to fire the redirect in the backing bean via.

```
<p:ajax event="close" listener="#{bean.goToStartPage}" />
```

Is there any other way to place the redirect to a new page after closing the dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution found [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/05/redirecting_fro.html) would be to redirect the ExternalContext in the bean method. This will redirect the page whether it's Ajax or not.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext extContext = ctx.getExternalContext();

String url = extContext.encodeActionURL(ctx.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(ctx, "/start.xhtml"));

try {
     extContext.redirect(url);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new FacesException(ioe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure JSF to do a proper redirect on an AJAX request, however if you do not wish to perform a redirect this way, I would invoke a hidden button that will trigger a full page postback to your managed bean method.

```
<p:ajax event="close" oncomplete="hiddenBtnWidget.jq.click()" />

...

<p:commandButton id="hiddenBtn" widgetVar="hiddenBudgetWidget" ajax="false"
    actionListener="#{bean.goToStartPage}" style="display: none;" />
```

As long as your listener is performing the redirect then this will redirect the page.